# Constructor note invoked while using java keyword from shell script or command prompt

Tags: java

Why constructor is not called while calling java class from shell script or command prompt instead it only enters main method? Why it is not creating an instance of the class?

Comment: The point of `main` being a static method is that it doesn't *need* an instance. If an instance were required, that would probably mean there'd have to be a parameterless constructor (as otherwise, how would the launcher know what values to provide for them?) which seems unnecessarily restrictive.

Comment: If your code needs an instance of your class, create it, e.g. as one of the first lines in `main()`. During creation of that instance, the constructor will be executed for that instance.